# Gmail freezes on display:none

Tags: html, gmail

I have a "div" which i insert in everypage, inside which resides my plugin. In certain pages where i might not need to use the plugin, i do a display:none on the div. This seems to work perfectly fine in all browsers. The only exception to this seems to be the "google.com" pages. Whether it be the search page or the gmail page, it seems to freeze once i do this display:none. By freeze i mean that none of the links are clickable after this. Is there something specific with these pages that i'm missing??

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if style="display:none" dose not work in gmail. put style="display:none !important;" .